# How do I SSH into EC2 with .pub?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

When I create a new Elastic Beanstalk environment it asked me if wanted to create a new keypair. I say yes, and it created two file in my `.ssh` folder locally called `app` and `app.pub`. Normally to ssh into an instance I use a `app.pem` file.

i.e

> ssh -i app.pem ubuntu@ip

Why did Elastic Beanstalk not give me `pem` file and how do I SSH into the instance without one?

Comment: the file `app` is most likely your private key file. This question is borderline off-topic for SO however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you need to create your key first in the AWS console, this will allow you to download the correct file `app.pem` which you add to `.ssh` folder (Mac).

You can then resign the new key by doing `eb ssh --setup`. **WARNING** This deletes all instances and recreates!